# How to rotate an array by moving N elements from end to start?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, char, rotation

I am trying to move a number of elements in an array to the end using C#.
I have an Array (in my case a char-array), and a integer `z`. Now I want to move `z` chars to the end of another array, the other chars should move to the beginning of the array.
So if the first array is `{'H','E','L','L','O'}` and `z = 3`, the new array should be `{'L','O','H','E','L'}`.

I hope somebody can help me.

Best attempt:

```
static char[] rotate(char[] c, int z)
{
    char[] nc = new char[c.Length];
    for (int i = z; i < c.Length; i++)
    {
        nc[i - z] = c[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < z; i++)
    {
        nc[i + z] = c[i];
    }
    return nc;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add your best not working attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the wrong indexing that was in your code.
Here's the fixed version:

```
static char[] rotate(char[] c, int z)
{
    char[] nc = new char[c.Length];
    for (int i = z; i < c.Length; i++)
    {
        nc[i - z] = c[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < z; i++)
    {
        nc[i + z - 1] = c[i]; // <-- Change here
    }
    return nc;
}
```

However, a better solution could be the usage of [doubly-linked lists](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/doubly_linked_list_algorithm.htm) that handles movement of the array items to start/end better. .NET implementation of doubly-linked list is [LinkedList Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1). And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203270/moving-items-in-linked-list-c-net) you can find some examples of how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`Array.Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=net-5.0)

> Copies a range of elements in one Array to another Array and performs
> type casting and boxing as required.

```
public static void DoStuff<T>(T[]source, int z)
{
   var start = source[0..z];
   Array.Copy(source, z, source, 0, source.Length - z);
   Array.Copy(start, 0, source, source.Length - z, z);
}
```

**Test**

```
var chars = "asdfghjk".ToCharArray();

DoStuff(chars, 3);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", chars));
```

Another way with an iterator

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DoStuff<T>(T[]source, int z) 
   => source.Select((t, i) => source[(i + z) % source.Length]);
```

Or using a for loop

```
public static T[] DoStuff<T>(T[]source, int z)
{
   var result = new T[source.Length];
   for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
      result[i] = source[(i + z) % source.Length];
   return result;
}
```

Super efficient zero allocations

```
public static unsafe void DoStuff(char[] source, int z)
{
   var start = stackalloc char[source.Length];
   fixed (char* pArray = source)
   {
      Buffer.MemoryCopy(pArray, start, z*sizeof(char), z * sizeof(char));
      Buffer.MemoryCopy(pArray+z, pArray, (source.Length-z)*sizeof(char) , (source.Length - z) * sizeof(char));
      Buffer.MemoryCopy(start, pArray+ (source.Length - z),  z * sizeof(char), z * sizeof(char));
   }
}
```

**Output**

```
f, g, h, j, k, a, s, d
```

<sub>***Note** : This lacks suitable input validation and range checking, and a descriptive name. I'll leave that up to you*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LINQ](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/linq/index.htm) in a single line without working on the array like that:

```
using System.Linq;

var letters = new[] { 'H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O' };

int posToRotate = 3;

var lettersRotated = letters.Skip(posToRotate).Concat(letters.Take(posToRotate)).ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(new string(lettersRotated));
```

That assumes `letters` is allocated and not null.

If the position is over than the length, nothing is done, but it can be checked before to avoid the processing (also negative indexes can be checked).

We [skip](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip) the first N characters (to take the rest), then we [add](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat) the first N characters we [take](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take).

We call [ToArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.toarray) because LINQ works on [IEnumerable<>](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1) (and IQueryable<>), so execution is [deferred](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-deferred-execution) until that here.

To replace the original array, just write:

```
letters = letters.Skip(posToRotate).Concat(letters.Take(posToRotate)).ToArray();
```

*Output*

```html
LOHEL
```